# Lua : self.array becomes NIL after using it to assign members of other object

Tags: class, oop, lua, null, lua-table

I had this class variable hash_tuples. When I am using that same variable to initialize member of other class Utils. The value somehow is becoming `nil`.

Posting minimal reproducible example of my problem.
Check lines with comments one of the print works while the other gives me error, the variable I just printed has become nil.

```
Utils = { list_tuples = {} }

function Utils:new(hash_tuples)
        o = o or {}
        setmetatable(o, self)
        self.__index = self

        self.list_tuples = hash_tuples
        return o
end


ConsistentHashing = { num_machines = 0, num_replicas = 0, hash_tuples = {}}

function ConsistentHashing:new(num_machines, num_replicas)
        -- check docs for these 3 lines
        o = o or {}
        setmetatable(o, self)
        self.__index = self

        self.num_machines = num_machines or 0
        self.num_replicas = num_replicas or 0

        for j = 1, self.num_machines, 1
        do
                for k = 1, self.num_replicas, 1
                do
                        table.insert(self.hash_tuples, {j,k, "hash_value"})

                end
        end
        return o
end

function ConsistentHashing:getMachine(key)
        print(#self.hash_tuples,table.concat(self.hash_tuples[12], ", ")) -- Works
        local ubu = Utils:new(self.hash_tuples)
        print(#self.hash_tuples,table.concat(self.hash_tuples[12], ", ")) -- Same line gives error

        return self.hash_tuples[index][1]
end

cs = ConsistentHashing:new(4, 3)
while(1)
do
        io.write("Please enter the key\n")
        local key = io.read()
        print (cs:getMachine(key))
end
```

Output :

```
Please enter the key
123
12      4, 3, hash_value
lua: temp.lua:37: attempt to get length of a nil value (field 'hash_tuples')
stack traceback:
        temp.lua:37: in method 'getMachine'
        temp.lua:47: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

How is this possible? What going behind the scenes?

**EDIT :** If I remove the index meta method I get another error

```
Please enter the key
54
lua: temp.lua:45: attempt to call a nil value (method 'getMachine')
stack traceback:
        temp.lua:45: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `o` is a global that never actually contained a `hash_tuples` field. On the line where the print works, it was accessing that field through the `__index` metamethod and actually getting it from `ConsistentHashing`. Calling `Utils:new` broke it, because it changed the metatable on `o` to be `Utils`, which doesn't provide a field that way.

I'm also pretty sure you got `self` and `o` backwards in a few places.

Comment: What do you mean by `you got self and o backwards in a few places`